# File not parsing (displays code) RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/708119/screenshot_%202010-02-04%20at%207.44.00%20PM.png)

I'm following a tutorial (book) about building rails apps but i ran into a problem and i can't figure how to solve it.

When i try to edit a product the page simply displays de code (with ruby code) and two question marks at the top. All the other views (create, show...) are correct so I can figure it out.

Any help?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What -are- those two question marks? My guess is that since Rails can't parse it as an erb file, it just displays it as is.

Comment: That's the problem. They are "nothing" because i don't have any characters there or in any other file that could generate those questions marks.

Comment: Well, when you open the file in textmate or whatever text editor, what do you see? Remove them. Mind you, you need a text editor that will open the file as-is, not some kind of word processor that will try to parse it.

Comment: Yes i'm using TextMate. The file looks perfect and all other files are build the same way. Even when displaying hidden characters, i get nothing but paragraphs.

Comment: Try this: Open the file in textmate, copy the text, close the file. Delete it, then create a new one with the same name, and paste in what you copied.. Then try to load it again.

Comment: That worked! Simple as that ah? Any ideia why that happened? Thanks a lot

Comment: It's what I said before - Rails couldn't parse the file so it displayed it instead. Who knows -why- that happened though. I blame you. :p

Answer (score 0):

Does your view file end with .erb.html?

Comment: Yes it end with .html.erb (de file was generated by rails it self, not created by me; i just edited it with a line of embedded code)